Local surjectivity theorem
Let $f:\Omega \to \mathrm{R^n}$ be a continuous map, differentiable at $x_0$ and such that $Df_{x_0}$ is invertible. I want to prove there exists $\epsilon>0$: $f$ is surjective in $B_\epsilon(f(x_0))$
WLOG: $x_0=0=f(x_0)$, $Df(0)=Id$ (the last assumption is justified by the fact that the differential map is invertible). I tried to prove the statement by contradiction.
Suppose $\forall \epsilon >0$ there exists $y \in 
\overline B_\epsilon(0)$ such that $y \neq f(x) \forall x \in \overline B_{\delta}(0)$ where $\delta$ is such that $f(\overline{B_{\delta}(0)}) \subseteq \overline B_\epsilon(0)$. I distinguish two cases:

y is a limit point in $\overline B_\epsilon(0)$. In that case I consider a sequence of points $f(x_n) \to y$. Since the closed ball is compact there is a subsequence $x_{n_k} \to \tilde{x} $ therefore by continuity of f: $y=\mathrm{lim}_{k \to \infty}f(x_{n_k})=f(\tilde x)$ which is the desired contradiction.

The second case is the one I am struggling with, that is when y is an isolated point in the epsilon ball. Intuitively I know that in this case $||f(x)-y||\geq r(y)$ and $||f(x)-x||\leq \sigma ||x||$ for some $\sigma \in \mathbb{R^+}$ because it is differentiable in zero so I would like to say that x and y get very close but still they may never touch and I can't use sequence-like arguments as before (at least I can't see them).
Any ideas?
I also tried to use the Banach fixed point theorem using $g=x-y+f(x)$ as a possible contraction but it doesn't seem to work in this case because I can't show it is a contraction.

You should try and define your notations more carefully. What are $x,y,z$? Fixed, variable? I’d also reduce the problem where $x_0=f(x_0)=0$ and $Df_{x_0}=\mathrm{id}$, because it may make the argument easier to see.

I want to prove that there is an open ball B whose center is $f(x_0)$ such that for every y in B there exists x such that $f(x)=y$. z is just an aribitrary point inside B because $g:B\to B$

Then please write as much in your question.

I tried to do something else using topological arguments, please let me know if you have any hints. Thanks in advance

Please, state the exact assumptions on $f$: You wrote "continuous" but you are using $Df_{x_0}$: What does this derivative even mean if the function is only continuous? Do you assume existence of partial derivatives at $x_0$, or differentiability at $x_0$, or $C^1$-smoothness in an open subset containing $x_0$, or something else?

I know it is differentiable only at $x_0$, now the question is edited

Yes, it is true and can be proven using the degree theory.

what is that? could you articulate a bit more? and since I know nothing about that, is there a simpler argument?

It is actually a powerful analytical tool for proving existence of solutions of nonlinear equations; if you want to study analysis, you should definitely learn it, see an overview here. I do not know an elementary argument for solving your problem.

Here is one way to prove this.
I will use the notation $B_r$ for the closed ball of radius $r$ in $\mathbb R^n$ centered at $0$. Set $B:=B_1$.
It suffices to consider the case of maps $f$ satisfying $f(0)=0$, with $x_0=0$, such that $B\subset \Omega$.
Let $A:= Df_{0}$; its is an invertible linear map of $\mathbb R^n$. By postcomposing $f$ with $A^{-1}$, it suffices to consider the case $Df_0=I$, the identity map.
For $t>0$ consider the family of maps $f_t: B\to \mathbb R^n$, $f_t(x)= \frac{1}{t} f(tx)$. The image $f_t(B)$ is the same as $\frac{1}{t} f(B_t)$. Thus, it suffices to show that for all sufficiently small $t$, $B_{1/2}\subset f_t(B)$ (this would imply that $B_{t/2}\subset f(B)$).
In view of differentiability of $f$ at $0$, by the very definition of derivative, we have uniform convergence on $B$
$$
\lim_{t\to 0} f_t= Df_0= I. 
$$
It is intuitive that since $f_t$ is close to the identity on $B$ (if $t\approx 0$), then its image $f_t(B)$ will contain the ball $B_{1/2}$. In order to justify this
intuition one uses Brouwer's Degree Theory. I understand that you are not familiar with this notion, so you just have to trust me to use it correctly. In our setting, for every continuous map $g: B\to \mathbb R^n$ and $y\in \mathbb R^n\setminus g(\partial B)$, the degree is an integer
$$
deg(g; B, y). 
$$
If $y\notin g(B)$, then this integer is zero. We also have $deg(I; B, y)=1$ for all $y$ in the interior of $B$, e.g. for all $y\in B_{1/2}$.
Thus, we only have to show that $deg(f_t; B, y)=1$ for all $y\in B_{1/2}$, provided that $t$ is sufficiently small.
The key property of degree is that it is "stable under small perturbations of a continuous map": If $g_t$ is a family of continuous maps of $B$ converging uniformly on $B$ to a continuous map $g$ (as $t\to 0$), then for all $y\in \mathbb R^n\setminus g(\partial B)$ we have
$$
\lim_{t\to 0} deg(g_t; B, y)= deg(g; B, y)
$$
and convergence is uniform as long as $y$ belongs to a fixed compact in $\mathbb R^n\setminus g(\partial B)$. In our case, we take $g_t=f_t$ and $g=I$. Then, for all sufficiently small $t$ and all $y\in B_{1/2}$ we have
$$
deg(f_t; B, y)= deg(I; B, y)=1. 
$$
Thus, $B_{1/2}\subset f_t(B)$ for all $t$ sufficiently small.
You can find a brief discussion of the degree theory in this article.
